# Matplotlib: Grid is too tight for small plot

Tags: matplotlib

I want to make the plot smaller, so it can save some space in print. However, when I make it smaller, the grid will be too tight:

[image]

Honestly, I don't get it. Why can't matplotlib auto-detect that this image is too small that the lable should be with a bigger interval?

So, How can I make the grid more sparse, so the lables won't overlap with each other?

Additionally, the title will also collapse with the labels. I can set it manually, by `plt.suptitle(title, y=1.08)`. So it will look better

[image]

But I'm wondering if there is anyway to do it automatically?

Note: I'm using `seaborn`, but I tried with pure `matplotlib`, same problem.

Comment: Are you manually specifying the ytick locations?

Comment: @Suever, no this occurs when I use a small figure size.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052844/matplotlib-how-to-decrease-density-of-tick-labels-in-subplots.

Comment: @VadimShkaberda This is very helpful. Is there any way I can do this automatically? For example, when I set fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14,2)), when the height is too tight, then triggers the `locator_params`?

Comment: The best I can suggest is to use for loop after `fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14,2))` like this (for 3 rows and 2 cols): `for i in range(6): plt.subplot(3, 2, i+1); plt.locator_params(axis='y', nbins=#number)`. Then plot your data as usual.