# matplotlib locator_params or set_major_locator not working

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to reduce the number of axis ticks in subplots (each axis different values, so I can't set the ticks manually), but other answers such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23534505/5553319) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13053967/5553319) don't work.
My syntax for creating the figure is standard, as follows:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7,9))
ax = fig.add_subplot(8,2,i+1) # I am plotting in a much larger loop, but I don't think there is anything wrong with the loop, because everything else (axis limits, labels, plotting itself...) works fine.
```

and to reduce the number of yticks, I tried

```
ax = plt.locator_params(nbins=4, axis='y')
```

which raised the error `TypeError: set_params() got an unexpected keyword argument 'nbins'`

and I tried

```
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(4))
```

which gave the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'yaxis'`

I don't understand why my subplot is considered to be a NoneType. I suspect this is the core of the problem, but all examples that I saw have the same structure, i.e.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(4))
```

and it should work. So why is my ax NoneType?

Comment: Yes, `fig = plt.figure(); ax = fig.add_subplot(111); ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(3))` should work and it does in my case. Are those the only lines in the script? How did you import pyplot?

Comment: Weird, in this case there must be something invisibly wrong with the stuff that I am actually plotting, which messes up the ax object. Imported pyplot the standard way, `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` but no, these are not the only lines in the script. There is a lot of data reading in and processing in order to plot them. But even if I comment everything else out, I still get the same error.

Comment: Could it be the problem that I create these subplots in a loop?
`for i,col in enumerate(column_list):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(8,2,i+1)`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the line:

```
ax = plt.locator_params(nbins=4, axis='y')
```

`locator_params` does not return an `Axes` instance (in fact it doesn't return anything), so on this line you are reassigning `ax` to be `None`.

I think you want to change it to:

```
ax.locator_params(nbins=4, axis='y')
```

and then it should all work ok.

Comment: In this case I get the `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'locator_params'`

Comment: In that case, you need to share more of your code, as you must have another command which is modifying `ax` before you get to that line

Comment: I see, a part of the problem was that I was saying `ax = plt.plot(...)` instead of `ax.plot(...)` - now changing this, `ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(7))` doesn't throw the error and even plots something, although it doesn't give the number of ticks I want. `ax.locator_params(nbins=4, axis='y')` still gives the same error.

Comment: Oh, I have a suspicion: the MaxNLocator doesn't work on a log scale, does it?

Comment: `MaxNLocator` shouldn't work on a logscale, correct. But it shouln't throw an error either, it will just not show any tickmarks. You can use the `LogLocator(base=10.0, subs=[1.0], numdecs=4, numticks=15)` instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, both methods lead to a miss-alignment of the labels and the figure. I.e. only the top of the labels are used and aligned over the whole figure. Instead, every Xth label should be used.