# matplotlib style ggplot doesn't show bars

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, python-ggplot

Does anybody know why `ggplot` is not showing bars in my case?

ggplot:

[image]

If I use classic, it looks like this:

[image]

my code looks like this:

```
style.use('ggplot')

def graph(candlestick_list):

    df = pd.DataFrame(candlestick_list)
    ohlc = df[['date', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close']]

    ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((6,1), (0,0), rowspan=5, colspan=1)
    ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((6,1), (5,0), rowspan=5, colspan=1, sharex=ax1)
    candlestick_ohlc(ax1, ohlc.values, width=0.5, colorup='g', colordown='r')
    ax2.bar(df['date'], df['volume'])
```

**UPDATE:**
After restarting the computer `ggplot` seems to show the bar plot, but shows now gaps. This is the current ggplot:
[image]

Comment: It looks to me that it has ticks... you just want to personalize them, maybe.

Have you tried with "ax1.set_tick_params(axis='x', direction='in',which='major')"
for ax1 and ax2, eventually major ticks, minor ticks, x and y?

https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_tick_params.html#matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_tick_params

Comment: Just tried it and got: `AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'set_tick_params'`

Comment: depends which class are you invoking, if you are in subplot or not.

There are several ways to plays with properties and ticks in subplots.

Have a look here:
https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html

and here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19626530/python-xticks-in-subplots

and this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052844/matplotlib-how-to-decrease-density-of-tick-labels-in-subplots

Comment: How many bars do you have? Does the problem still occur if you use less bars?

Comment: If I use less bars, the problem doesn't occur. But other ones, like the bars merging with each others

Answer (score 0):

You can try to adjust ticks using `plt.setp(axes, xticks=list(range(0, 24, 5)))`. You can also adjust `yticks`, the same way shown for "x".